# HTML5 SVG links to relative url targets not working

Tags: svg, hyperlink

I've checked all the other questions and answers about this.

I have a problem linking to a target in svg that is within an HTML5 page.

It appears that the xlink:href="#target" only works if you specify an http:// within the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<!--<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">-->
<head>
    <title>Womble</title>



</head>

<body>


<div class="holder">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  version="1.1" width="1000" height="1000">

  <a xlink:href="#target" >

  <text x="10" y="25" >Zoom in on shape below</text>

  </a>
  <a xlink:href="svglinktest.htm#target2" >

      <text x="10" y="50" >Zoom in on shape below 2</text>

  </a>
  <a xlink:href="svglinktest.htm#target3(viewBox(500, 800, 100, 100))" >

      <text x="10" y="75" >Zoom in on shape below 3</text>

  </a>


  <view name="target" id="target" title="target" viewBox="800 800 100 100">
    <rect x="800" y="800" width="100" height="100"/>
  </view>
  <view name="target" id="target2" title="target" viewBox="600, 800, 100, 100">
    <rect x="600" y="800" width="100" height="100"/>
  </view>
  <view name="target" id="target2" title="target">
    <rect x="500" y="800" width="100" height="100"/>
  </view>
</svg>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to get it to work on a local machine - as the pages run offline without a server.
I've tried to use a different name space (commented out) and .xhtml as suggested elsewhere, and looked at the W3C specifications, and tried a few different things but do not seem to get any luck with any browser.

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Otherwise I will have to do a lot of jquery for something that in HTML is very basic.

Regards

Comment: Thanks. OK, thanks for confirming what I had suspected.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the syntax for viewSpec all wrong, but even if you had it right it only works on SVG documents and not on SVG embedded in a html document.